# Cant boot - new drive and incorrect DeviceID

Tags: windows-10, boot, hard-drive-recovery, bcdedit

Working on Dad's computer.  Hard drive had 0KB available.

Bought new SSD. Used Clonezilla to create image and then attempted to restore.  Windows then failed to load.

I ended up running:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device boot
bcdedit /set {default} device boot
bcdedit /set {default} osdevice boot
```

Now, neither the old or new hard drive will boot.

Now it simply says:

```
No boot device available
Strike the F1 key to reboot, f2 to run the setup utility
SATA 1 installed
SATA 2 installed
Sata 3 installed
SATA 4 none
SATA 5 none
```

I was unable to create a window restore disk from this PC due to the space issue. I have a Windows restore from a different machine that I'm trying to use to repair.

Can anyone help walk me through reconfiguring the device ID for my new hard drive?

Reformat is a very very last resort as we have no windows 10 CD because this was an upgraded Windows 7 from the free upgrade program from a couple years ago.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Now, neither the old or new hard drive will boot." - If the old drive wasn't installed at the time then the reason the old drive cannot boot is unrelated to those commands.

Comment: I'm thinking I blew out the boot information from the boot manager when I ran the commands.  I believe if I run the command bcdedit it should indicate the ID from the hard drive and other various information, but mine now says:  "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found"

Comment: Can I just reinstall Windows over the top of itself as I did many years ago prior to Windows 10?

Comment: Nope... It says upgrade not available if you started your computer with Windows installation media.  Does anyone have suggestions on correcting the bootmgr (or whatever is preventing the computer from locating the correct boot info)?

Comment: Who was that comment directed to exactly?